# Add key-value of different dictionaries and store it another dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, slice

I have something like this

```
stud_1 = {'stud_2' : 1, 'stud_3' : 3, 'stud_4' : 2,'stud_5' : 5,'stud_6' : 1,'stud_7' : 3,'stud_8' : 4,'stud_9' : 3}
stud_2 = {'stud_1' : 3, 'stud_3' : 2, 'stud_4' : 4,'stud_5' : 2,'stud_6' : 1,'stud_7' : 5,'stud_8' : 1,'stud_9' : 2}
stud_3 = {'stud_1' : 1, 'stud_2' : 5, 'stud_4' : 3,'stud_5' : 5,'stud_6' : 5,'stud_7' : 2,'stud_8' : 3,'stud_9' : 5}
stud_4 = {'stud_1' : 4, 'stud_2' : 3, 'stud_3' : 2,'stud_5' : 1,'stud_6' : 5,'stud_7' : 3,'stud_8' : 1,'stud_9' : 4}
.....
.....
```

and so on till `stud_9`. the values are the marks out of five each student has received

I want to add the key-values with each other and store it another dictionary. 
Like add the value of key `stud_1` in the dictionaries other than `stud_1` itself and then store it in a new dictionary with key as `stud_1`.

How do I do that?

**Edit** :

If I consider only these 4 dictionaries here, the final dictionary should be

```
final_dict = {'stud_1' : 9 , 'stud_2' : 9 , 'stud_3' : 7, 'stud_4' : 9 ....}  ## and so on according to the key value
```

Comment: Can you post the exact output you want?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a collections.Counter for this , and then update each dictionary into that Counter . Example -

```
from collections import Counter
s1c = Counter(stud_1)
s1c.update(stud_2)
s1c.update(stud_3)
.
.
.
```

Counter is a subclass of dict , so you can later on use s1c as a simple dictionary.

When you update a Counter , the values are added from the incoming dictionary/Counter , instead of overwriting.

Comment: Works like a charm. But how do I convert it back to a dictionary ?

Comment: You do not actually need to , but if you really want to , try - dict(s1c) .

Comment: Yes, it worked. So max(s1c, key = s1c.get) works in the case of Counter ?

Comment: Yes it works. Like I said Counter is a subclass of dict, so nearly everything you can do with dict, you can do with Counter.

Answer (score 0):

Use `dictionary.iteritems()` to iterate over each dictionary and append them to the first one.

```
for k,v in dict.iteritems():
    dict2[k] = v
```

Or you could use `dictionary.update()`:

```
dict1.update(dict2)
```

Comment: how do I add the different dictionary values ?

Comment: You can either use `for k,v in dictionary.iteritems(): dict[k] = v` or you could use another method which is `dict1.update(dict2)`.